# After I deployed my project on laravel, I got an error

Tags: php, laravel

After I deployed my laravel project on the domain and only the homepage is working. And the rest when i click, they gave this error:

404. That’s an error.
     The requested URL was not found on this server.

Can someone afford my question please?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: the information you provided is not enough provide us the log.

Comment: is the project working in localhost ?

Comment: how is the project hosted ?

Comment: Can you show us please the structure of your app?

Comment: What web server that you use? If you use `apache` you should enable url rewriting. Or maybe there are some misconfiguration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your .htaccess file  in your public folder.

Answer (score 0):

First check / set up your routes file.

Look at the file `routes/web.php` in your application directory and you will see the list of URLs your app will respond to.

If something isn't in that list your app will give a 404.

Also do `php artisan route:list` to see the same information in another form.  That is the definitive list of routes the app will respond to.